# Many Errors when Web-Scraping with splashr including Error in execute_lua(splash_obj, call_function) : Gateway Timeout (HTTP 504)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, http-status-code-504

I'm trying to use `splashr` to scrape a dynamic webpage, and it's been non-stop problems for me. During my scrape of `get_box_score()`, I'll either get the errors

```
Error in execute_lua(splash_obj, call_function) : 
Gateway Timeout (HTTP 504).
```

or

```
Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to 
an object of class "xml_missing"
```

And honestly, once I "fix" one of the errors, I get the other. I have no idea if these are related, or if I'm just getting a lot of different unrelated errors with my code. Any idea how I can fix these? Here's my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(splashr)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.uscho.com/scoreboard/michigan/mens-hockey/"  

# Everything should be fine for a while
get_data <- function(myurl) {

  link_data <- myurl %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes("td:nth-child(13) a") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    str_c("https://www.uscho.com", .) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    set_names("url")

  game_type <- myurl %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes("td:nth-child(12)") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    set_names("game_type") %>%
    filter(game_type != "Type")

  as_tibble(data.frame(link_data, game_type))

}

link_list <- get_data(url)

urls <- link_list %>%
  filter(game_type != "EX") %>%
  pull(url)

# Here's where the fun starts
get_box_score <- function(my_url) {

  progress_bar$tick()$print()
  Sys.sleep(15)
  splash_container <- start_splash()
  on.exit(stop_splash(splash_container))
  Sys.sleep(10)

  mydata <- splash_local %>%
    splash_response_body(TRUE) %>%
    splash_user_agent(ua_win10_chrome) %>%
    splash_go(my_url) %>%
    splash_wait(runif(1, 5, 10)) %>%
    splash_html() %>%
    html_node("#boxgoals") %>%
    html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
    as_tibble()

  return(mydata)
}

progress_bar <- link_list %>%
  filter(game_type != "EX") %>%
  tally() %>%
  progress_estimated(min_time = 0)

mydata <- pmap_df(list(urls), get_box_score)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. 504 is a server-side error; it the server cannot handle the requests in time.

But you can still fix it by adjusting your code; you can try the following methods:

- Slow down your request, use `Sys.sleep()` to pause between each request, if you make requests too fast, the server may not be able to handle it and may consider you like a robot and ban you. As a result, you will receive 504 error.
- use `try()` or `tryCatch()` function to skip errors and prevent them from breaking your loop. You can also write code to automatically try to make another request if the request failed.